# What happened with the [dragonfly] tag? Did someone just remove it?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I'm confused what happened with [dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly)?

Did it just got removed?  What happened with all those questions that were marked with the tag?

Why is there no more guidance of which tags must be used instead?!  This is no good!

Answer (score 6):

Well, a synonym has been proposed (but not approved) to redirect [dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly) into [opera-dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-dragonfly). There is not currently a [dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly) ***at all***, so yes it must have been removed. I will check the audit to see when/why that happened.

edit: it was removed automatically because it wasn't being used:

```
Type:   TagsDestroyed
Created:    5 hours ago (2016-07-05 04:02:49Z)
Agent:  assign-tag-badges-and-tune
Message:    dragonfly
```

It looks like the last few posts marked [dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly) were additionally tagged [dragonfly-mail-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly-mail-agent) (by you), and later had [dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly) removed. This presents some interesting questions about whether [dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly) should mean the agent or the client.

There is some guidance that appears in the tag-editor when typing "dragonfly". I invite people to improve the text on these to make it easier for users:

[image]

Because this is so ambiguous and could cause confusion with unrelated topics, I have now added a blacklist with guidance text:

[image]

Comment: this vandalism should be reverted.  dragonfly should not redirect to opera-dragonfly

Comment: @cnst I think it is premature to call it vandalism; is there any reason that [tag:opera-dragonfly] is inappropriate?

Comment: @cnst as for "Why is there no more guidance of which tags must be used instead?!" - I can approve the synonym proposal, in which case it will not just be "guidance", but ***fully automatic*** (including any pre-existing feeds, links, etc)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Do that and he's going to melt down in a most spectacular fashion :p

Comment: @BoltClock well, that may be the case, but if [tag:dragonfly] and [tag:opera-dragonfly] *mean the same thing* (and I'm guessing they do), then there absolutely should be a synonym; and I kinda agree with the consensus that [tag:opera-dragonfly] is more specific

Comment: It seems that "dragonfly" is [ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12893617). I'm not sure if we should make it a synonym.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I agree (see my recent edit) - there is a big question over whether this should mean the agent or the client

Comment: @S.L. Barth: Huh. Now it's even more puzzling why the OP is *so* worked up about the tag disappearing. The tag is ambiguous so we're better off without it, aren't we?

Comment: @BoltClock Maybe OP wanted that, if someone starts typing "dragonfly" as a tag, the tagger would get a warning about the ambiguity. The tag is highly likely to be re-introduced by a hapless asker or editor.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I can blacklist "dragonfly" as a tag easily, including adding guidance text - like we do with "google", for example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4mLdt.png ; update: done - see image in answer

Comment: There were hundreds of posts marked [tag:dragonfly] just a day ago.  The fact that you (as an administrator of the whole site) cannot see it is disconcerting.  The fact that someone does such a big job of removing it all and merging it with a tag for a product that has been discontinued a few years ago is also something that's been unexplained...  Is this really the MD here?  Someone messes up the site, someone else has to notice the mess up by accident, the admins have no idea what's going on and noone's responsible?

Comment: @cnst well, around 40 of them: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508023/what-was-tagged-dragonfly - I'll take a look at the histories, but... frankly I have to agree that the tag "dragonfly" is incredibly ambiguous and is a bad choice of tag; it *looks* like the user Kara has edited a bunch of them, and reviewing the changes, it looks like they did a good job of picking between the different meanings of "dragonfly". If anything, I applaud their efforts...

Comment: @cnst to put it another way; we can see what *has happened*; what I want to understand is what your *concern* is; it *looks* like a confused and ambiguous tag has been split out into clearer separate tags (which mostly already existed - this was just a final cleanup); this seems like a good thing. If you disagree, please let me know *why* you disagree, and how just having "dragonfly" would be better.

Comment: I disagree with the procedure employed; that the summary of the tag being ambiguous got removed; and that the new disambiguation does not mention DragonFly BSD, which predates all the other DragonFly projects (and will likely postdate them as well).

Comment: @cnst if your concern is not mentioning "dragonfly-bsd" in the popup; we can change that trivially; but "predates" is not a useful comparison/metric here (especially since we're not trying to decide who "wins" [tag:dragonfly]); I have edited the copy [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fodxz.png) - I've listed the 3 examples in the order in which they appear in the tag helper popup (which is: by usage quantity)